# Testing Laravel Inside Legacy Application

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework, phpunit, legacy-code

Chances are pretty high that it's impossible to help me without being able to see this codebase I'm in but I though I'd ask here just in case someone has done something similar

I'll go into more specific details about the situation I'm in below, but the main question I'm asking is: Has anyone had to write tests for a legacy codebase that uses Laravel as a dependancy and were you able to use Laravel's TestCase or did you have to role your own testing environment?

I'm working in a 15+ year old legacy php app... About a year ago they started writing a bunch of their new API in Laravel. The legacy app includes the Laravel app as a dependency. So what happens is, via `htaccess` rewrite rule, requests going to `api/v2` hit an index file that boots the Laravel app. This index file includes an `init.inc.php` which does a ton of setup for the legacy app, then when the Laravel app gets booted, it actually boots a custom class which extends Laravel's `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`. It does this because there's a bunch of legacy configurations that get passed to `Zend_Config` and then sets the storage directory to point inside of the legacy app instead of the laravel app.

The Laravel app is a private packagist that gets symlinked to a local copy of the repo during development. During production, it's just a vendor package.

I'm trying to set up tests for this damn thing... and it is not going well lol

I was really hoping to be able to have a test suite within the Laravel app itself but it doesn't look like I'll be able to do so, because the bootstrap flow is created under the assumption that the legacy app does all of its set up before spinning up Laravel, and of course, the Laravel app has dependencies on the legacy app too.

So what I've been trying to settle on is setting up the tests inside the legacy app, and run the standard boot sequence, followed by spinning up Laravel. I can actually get this to work with a `BaseTestCase` class the extends `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` and I can get my Eloquent models instantiated inside of a test, I can hit endpoints with Guzzle and assert on responses etc... all seems to work fine

Problem is I don't have an easy way to test anything in isolation at this point, so touching the database is kind of my first go-to method for now. However, I also don't have an easy way for seeding test data, and I don't have an easy way to wrap my tests in transactions that rollback after each test. (I may have to go this route honestly, but it seems like it could lead to a lot of work) What would be amazing is if I could just use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` then I'd have all the Laravel goodies like not having to work directly with Guzzle for one, but also traits like `DatabaseTransactions` and `WithoutEvents` or `WithoutMiddleware` etc.

Something is not right though. When I try extending the Laravel TestCase I get weird errors like `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setEventDispatcher() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher, null given,`

Diving through some source code it looks like `TestCase` checks if the `app` has been instantiated, and if not calls the abstract `createApplication()` method which is defined on my custom `TestCase` but the error I'm getting is telling me that `$app['events']` is `null`. Ugh, and of course, I can't get Xdebug working in their environment either so I'm not able to properly step through and see exactly what's going on.

Basically, my main goal right now is to figure out how to get debugging working with their setup, so I can actually step through code but I figured I would put a question out here on StackOverflow in case someone has any advice. Anything that gets me closer to being able to use the Laravel TestCase would be an amazing feeling right now.

I know it's a long shot but anyone ever try anything like this before? Were you able to get a Laravel test suite working in a legacy app?

**Edit**

Here's what my `createApplication` override looks like after removing actual paths with fake ones:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    @set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../www-root/core",
        dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../www-root/core/includes",
        dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../www-root/core/library",
        dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../www-root/core/library/vendor",
        get_include_path(),
    )));

    require_once("init.inc.php");

    $this->app = require_once 'private-packagist-package/src/bootstrap/app.php';

    $kernel = $this->app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );

    $response->send();

    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
}
```

That same code works in my barebones test case where I simply extend PHPUnit's test case.

Comment: Can you share the code for your version of `createApplication()` ?

Comment: @AngadDubey Yep, updated the post.